# Node/NPM is updating package.json and package-lock.json file in my home directory instead of project directory

Tags: node.js, macos, npm

I want to play around with a simple babylonjs toy project and I created a directory on my computer for it at `~/workspace/babylon-test`. I then navigate to that directory. So the commands look like this:

```
mkdir ~/workspace/babylon-test
cd ~/workspace/babylon-test
```

I use `pwd` to verify that I am currently inside the `babylon-test` directory.

I run the following command, [recommended from the Babylon docs](https://github.com/BabylonJS/Babylon.js), to install the babylonjs modules:

```
npm install babylonjs --save
```

I go to inspect my current directory (`babylon-test`) and it's empty:

```
$ pwd
/Users/myuser/workspace/babylon-test
$ ls -al
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   2 myuser  staff    64 Apr 18 13:05 .
drwxr-xr-x  47 myuser  staff  1504 Apr 18 13:05 ..
```

However, it seems `package.json` and `package-lock.json` were created or updated in my home directory:

```
$ ls -al ~
total 22720
drwxr-xr-x+ 137 myuser  staff     4384 Apr 18 12:58 .
drwxr-xr-x    5 root     admin      160 Apr  9  2018 ..
<lots of files and subdirectories listed here, omitting for brevity and scope>
drwxr-xr-x  780 myuser  staff    24960 Apr 18 21:20 node_modules
-rw-r--r--    1 myuser  staff   896008 Apr 18 21:14 package-lock.json
-rw-r--r--    1 myuser  staff      148 Apr 18 13:06 package.json
```

Looking at `~/package.json` I see its contents are:

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "electron": "^13.1.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babylonjs": "^5.2.0"
  }
}
```

I remember trying to install Vue and the Vue CLI several months ago, and I'm wondering if I messed up my Node/NPM configuration somehow.

Shouldn't I see a `package.json` and `package-lock.json` file be generated inside my `/workspace/babylon-test` directory? And *not* in my homedir? If so, what can I do to troubleshoot and see what's going on?

Comment: Did you create a package in your test dir for it to be installed to?

Comment: Thanks but no I didn't, I was just following the Babylon docs which said to run `npm install babylonjs --save`. What should I have done first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `npm init` first on your pwd and then do `npm install`
Ref: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-init

Comment: Thanks (and +1), so it _sounds_ like I should have: (1) created my `babylon-test` directory and then (2) created an empty `package.json` file? If so what are the next steps, in order? At what point do I run `npm install babylonjs --save` like the Babylon docs say? Thanks again!

Comment: `npm init` would created the package.json for you. you can run `npm install babylonjs --save` right away when you have the package.json

Answer (score 1):

A `package.json` file needs to exist for NPM to install packages. Run `npm init -y` to quickly create a `package.json`. Then when you run `npm install` it'll append it to the `dependencies` array in your `package.json` and install the dependencies to the `node_modules` folder of your project.

Comment: Thanks (and +1), so it _sounds_ like I should have: (1) created my `babylon-test` directory and then (2) created an empty `package.json` file? If so what are the next steps, in order? At what point do I run `npm install babylonjs --save` like the Babylon docs say? Thanks again!